# Selecting from AngularJS dropdown in Protractor.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have searched to forums over and over again - tried to make sense of some of what people have said, but the solutions never seem to fit my case.

My problem concerns selecting an item from a drop down list that has been coded in AngularJS on a website. I am running automated tests using Protractor and a Selenium server. Right now I am running different scripts I have coded on various websites that have been coded in AngularJS. Its fascinating to see something I code fill out a form automatically - so cool!

Unfortunately whenever I come across a drop down in my test I try and come up with a solution for hours and never have been able to figure it out. So I have come to stack!!

This is the code I am working with it's actually jetblue's sign up website so if you want to take a look go here: https://trueblue.jetblue.com/web/trueblue/register/
The trouble starts on page two with the dropdowns - don't know how to fill out a single one.

Thanks,
FB

```
    <div class="row has-dropdown form-value error" style="z-index: 108; position: relative;"> <label for="my-info-title"> <span aria-hidden="true">*</span> <span class="visuallyHidden">required</span> Title
<div class="tb-select accountData_title"><span class="tb-select-title error">Select</span><div class="tb-select-dropdown"><ul><li class="selected" title=""><span>Select</span></li><li title="DR"><span> Dr
</span></li><li title="JT"><span> Jetter
</span></li><li title="MISS"><span> Miss
</span></li><li title="MR"><span> Mr
</span></li><li title="MRS"><span> Mrs
</span></li><li title="MS"><span> Ms
</span></li></ul></div><select name="accountData_title" class="my-info-title-select" id="my-info-title" style="display: none;"> <option value="">Select</option> <option value="DR"> Dr
</option>  <option value="MISS"> Miss
</option> <option value="MR"> Mr
</option> <option value="MRS"> Mrs
</option> <option value="MS"> Ms
```

Comment: element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'MISS')).click(); or if that gets fussy with MR vs MRS, $('[value="MR"]').click();

Answer (score 0):

`title: ElementFinder = $('select#my-info-title');
list: ArrayElementFinder = $('select#my-info-title > option');`

First perform the `title.click()`[This clicks on the title dropdown]. Then choose the title you want to select.

eg: `list.get(1).click()` which chooses the title as `DR`

Hope this gives the answer for your problem.

Note: The solution is given with CSS Selectors and typescript.

if the above method fails try the below alternate function.

```
var selectDropdownbyNum = function ( element, optionNum ) {
      if (optionNum){
        var options = element.all(by.tagName('option'))   
          .then(function(options){
            options[optionNum].click();
          });
      }
    };
```

Hope above functions helps you!!

## 0506

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried to upvote you but didn't have enough reputation for it to count.